# plot function does not take plot type into account in R language

Tags: r, plot, visualization

I have the following R script:

```
X <- read.table("/tmp/run178/data/monitor/portal_free_heap_monitor.log", header=T, sep=";")

P1 <- subset(X, Server=="PortalServer1")
P2 <- subset(X, Server=="PortalServer2")

png("mygraph.png")
plot(P1$Time, P1$HeapFreePercent, type="l", col="red")
lines(P2$Time, P2$HeapFreePercent, col="green")
q()
```

In resulting PNG image data for "PortalServer1" is drawn with dots and in black, but it's supposed to be drawn with red lines. The other one is drawn as expected with green lines. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**: Here is the structure of the X:

```
> str(X)
'data.frame':   5274 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ Time           : Factor w/ 2654 levels "2011.08.24 14:39:29",..: 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 ...
 $ Server         : Factor w/ 2 levels "PortalServer1",..: 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 ...
 $ HeapFreePercent: int  42 49 41 49 41 49 41 49 41 49 ...
```

Comment: What data type is `P1$Time`?  Please paste the results of `str(P1)` into your question.

Comment: @Andrie, I updated question with information about X structure

Comment: You probably don't want `$Time` as a factor. Convert it to something useful like a `?POSIXct` object and then R will do something somewhat more appropriate with it.

Comment: Your question led me to the idea and I tried to convert Time column to be a proper datetime, and then it worked with the plot function, but why didn't it work in the first attempt?

Comment: time_format <- "%Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%S"

Comment: plot(strptime(P1$Time, time_format), P1$HeapFreePercent, type="l", col="red")

Comment: It didn't work the first time because R isn't a mind reader. It saw characters/strings for your date/times and by default will convert those to factors. The only other thing it could have done was leave them as characters, but that wouldn't have plotted correctly either. @Andrie has explained this more I see.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

@GavinSimpson already commented on how to fix your problem.  This should have been a comment, but is too long.  I simply explain what happened to your plot with your data in its original form.

You are plotting data of type `factor`.  Consequently when you call the function `plot`, the S3 method dispatching will invoke `plot.factor`.

If you read the help for `?plot.factor` you will notice that the type of plot you then get also depends on the type of your second parameter.  Since this is also a factor, ultimately your plot is drawn by `spineplot`.  Thus your `type="l"` is essentially ignored.  The colour is plotted in red, though...

Reverse engineering your data, I get something like this:

```
X <- data.frame(
    Time = sort(sample(letters, 100, replace=TRUE)),
    Server = sample(c("PortalServer1", "PortalServer2"), 100, replace=TRUE),
    HeapFreePercent = runif(100))
str(X)

P1 <- subset(X, Server=="PortalServer1")
P2 <- subset(X, Server=="PortalServer2")

plot(P1$Time, P1$HeapFreePercent, type="l", col="red")
lines(P2$Time, P2$HeapFreePercent, col="green")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for in depth explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

A somewhat hacky solution but it works for all factors, not just timestamps.

Change

```
plot(P1$Time, P1$HeapFreePercent, type="l", col="red")
lines(P2$Time, P2$HeapFreePercent, col="green")
```

to

```
plot(P1$Time, P1$HeapFreePercent, type="n")
lines(P1$Time, P1$HeapFreePercent, type="l", col="red")
lines(P2$Time, P2$HeapFreePercent, col="green")
```

This code first draws no actually data, just axis. Then it draws the real data using `lines`, which avoids calling `plot.factor`